# How to monitor RCP e4 applications using Sleak plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4, sleak

I am using Eclipse 2019-09 with RCP e4 and the Sleak Plugin.

I am trying to get the Sleak view to monitor an application but either get 
a "Device is not tracking resource allocation" using the debug/run configurations trace options method or monitor the eclipse IDE resources using the .options file with -debug in the eclipse.ini before vmargs method.

A similiar question exists here [Sleak (SWT & RCP) : Device is not tracking resource allocation (eclipse 4.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460698/sleak-swt-rcp-device-is-not-tracking-resource-allocation-eclipse-4-3) but wasn't answered.

Comment: Those methods only apply to a 3.x compatability mode RCP. It does not look like e4 supports this because of the way E4Application creates the Display.

Comment: ok thanks @greg-449 is there an alternative plugin resource monitor that can be used?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639364/2670892) where I have worked out how to to do the initialization for an e4 application